# How to save the users data while signing in nextjs using nex-auth?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I'm new to next-auth. When I click on the sign in button it takes me to the google sign in page. It shows the list of accounts. After clicking one of the accounts, it shows the image and email.

This signIn() function is from the module `next-auth/react`. If I want to save the user's email and image in a database, how will I do it? I want to have the user's email and image saving process happen the moment users click on any of their account.

Where do I write the code for saving the user data in the database that involves typical DB steps like using the model for data, DB connection, etc?

*//pages/index.js:*

```js
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>
        <img src={session.user.image} />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Not signed in</p>
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*//pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js*

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    })
  ],
});
```

Comment: It depends of the database you are using as there are different adapters. See https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/overview.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to use an [adapter](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/overview):

> An **Adapter** in NextAuth.js connects your application to whatever
> database or backend system you want to use to store data for users,
> their accounts, sessions, etc.

So you can go to the NextAuth documentation and read about the database you are using in the adapters section.

The type of adapter will vary based on what type of backend / database you are using, in my case I'm using prisma with mongoDB so my next auth endpoint `[...nextauth].ts` would be as the following:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import {PrismaAdapter} from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const client = new PrismaClient(); 

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(client), 
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a good example. you can use callbacks to save user data or perform any kind of checks while the user is signing in. in this example, when the user will select their Gmail id, just after that signin callback will be called. in this, you can check if the user already exists or not. accodingly you can decide to save the data (si

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import SignToken from "@/lib/SignToken";
import axios from "axios";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      const response = await axios.post(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + "/auth/userExists",
        { email: profile?.email }
      );
      if (response && response.data?.value === true) {
        return true;
      } else {
        const data = {
          firstName: profile.given_name,
          lastName: profile.family_name,
          email: profile.email,
          profileUrl: profile.picture,
        };
        const response = await axios.post(
          process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + "/auth/signup",
          data
        );
        return true;
      }
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      console.log('called jwt');
      console.log(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser);
      if (account) {
        const userLoggedIn = await SignToken(user?.email as string);
        token.loggedUser = userLoggedIn;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.loggedUser = token.loggedUser;
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```